# How can I retrieve the data from google sheet to manifest.json

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, plugins, browser-extension, manifest.json

How can I retrieve the data of a column in google sheet(which updates after a google form is submitted) to my manifest.json file.

Basically, I am creating a chrome extension that blocks some specific links, these links are the data in the column on the google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would approach this problem is using Google Apps Script to create a REST API. This would allow the chrome extension to query an endpoint and receive data from the Google Sheet.

Here is a tutorial for how to create the API: https://trevorfox.com/2015/03/rest-api-with-google-apps-script/

You could then make a fetch request from the extension's background script and chrome storage to store the blacklisted links.

Comment: thank you, I will try this. was hoping there was something easier tho.